# Refresh Entity in Entity Framework 4.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to create an API to allow same functionality from the web application as well.
Web Application and API uses the same data access layer that is running on top of Entity Frameowrk 4.0

For example,

From API, i do 
  1) Get UsersEntry
  2) Update UsersEntry.OnTrial = false, UserEntry.Enabled = true

From Web Application, I do
  1) Update UserEntry.OnTrial = true

Now when i go back to API function, and then try to get the UserEntry.OnTrial valu, it returns false, as it was cached in the memory as a value false last time it accessed. It should have the latest value.

The way i get the value via API is
   DBContecx.Database.User.Entry.Single(u => u.username == emailAddress).

Is it possible for me to access the actual database instead of reading from memory when using API?

Please help.
Thanks,
Vivek

Comment: So you're saying that the EF cache isn't being invalidated properly so that you get the latest value?

Comment: Sounds like your DBContext is not being disposed of on each request in the webapi.

Comment: DbContexts don't do any sort of data caching between requests, so your problem must lie elsewhere.

Comment: You can also try `db.UsersEntry.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;`

Comment: Just to clarify what I think McKee means, dbcontexts **DO** cache objects between **queries**, but not between **web requests** because usually your requests should be stateless and thus the context disposed of.

Comment: @AaronLS Correct.  Sorry, I should have said Web Requests.  I guess you could have stuck your DbContext into Session or Application, but that wouldn't be a very good idea in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: Vivek, I think the message is clear: use one context instance per web request.